# How to find best threshold for an image using connected region method

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-thresholding

In theory the best threshold value is a mean of grasyscale interval which number of connected regions do not change but how to find it in matlab?

Comment: "In theory the best threshold value is...": where do you draw this from ???

Comment: From my lessons about thresholding but maybe it can just be okey for an image has a bimodal histogram

Comment: This problem is directly related to the watershed algorithm and the MSER blob detector.

Comment: In the end, are you interested in a good/best way to threshold a grayscale image or how to threshold an image using connected regions?  May or may not be the same thing, depending on what your your criteria are for "best".  An easy candidate for a single threshold would be to use Otsu's method, which is implemented in the graythresh and imbinarize commands.  An easy multi-threshold would be kmeans (imsegkmeans).  As @YvesDaoust mentioned, for the connected region technique, you probably want to look at things like watershed.